# How to store Azure app services diagnostic logs to Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics, azure-web-app-service, log-analysis

I want to store my api's (hosted on app services) logs to Azure Table storage using Azure Diagnostics. Currently I can store the logs on blob container I am unable to find a option to store on the Table storage.

After some google searching I found that classic azure portal supported to store logs on table storage. When I try to log-in into classic portal it automatically redirects me to the current portal.

Basically I want to view the logs using Azure Log Analytics where I'm unable to view the logs from a blob container.

Please show me some light on this issue. Either enlighten me by showing a way to bind logs in Azure Log Analytics from a blob container or showing me a way to store app services diagnostic logs to table storage.

Comment: Is it enough if you are able to log Azure Storage Table ?

Comment: Yes Thomas. I'll be able to import the logs using LogAnalytics then.

Comment: You should have a look at semantic logging :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx. There is an appender to log to Azure Table :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775011(v=pandp.20).aspx. Do you need more information, samples ?

Comment: A sample would be great..

Comment: Thanks for the link but I was talking about web server logs. Azure diagnostics provide logging for web webservers hosted in app services. I don't have any code for logging in my application. Rather the IIS logs are currently stored in Blog storage. I was wondering if I can store them in azure table storage.